# Can the simple function in a product space be chosen this way?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is a classical proof that if you have a positive function n any measure-space, there is a monotone sequence that converges pointwise to this function.

If you have two measure-spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mu)$, and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2,\mu_2)$, and you have a positive function in this space $f: \Omega_1\times \Omega_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that is $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{A}_2$ measurable, you can then find a sequence of simple functions $s_n$ that converges pointwise to f, where $s_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{K(n)}a_{n_i}\mathcal{X}_{A_{k_i}}$, where $A_{k_i}$ is a set in $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{A}_2$. But I am wondering if $A_{k_i}$, can be chosen $A_{k_i}^1\times A_{k_i}^2$, where $A_{k_i}^1 \in \mathcal{A}$, and $A_{k_i}^2 \in \mathcal{A}_2$?

I am not really sure how to show this. In the classical proof  for each n, you cut of at n, and you take inverse images of $[k\cdot 2^{-n},(k+1)\cdot2^{-n})$. If we do this in this case we get the general sets in $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{A}_2$, but I don't see how to decouple this? Can you please help?

Comment: Are you requiring $s_n$ to converge monotonically to $f$ or just pointwise?

Answer (score 1):

No. For example $f=\chi_D$, where $D=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]:x=y\}$.